# One way sync with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization

I am about to build an internal-only iOS app for storing simple business data. The data store will consist of a single entity only, with one entry per day. To start with there will be around two years worth of data (~750 entries).

I want to set the app up to do one-way syncing only. i.e. Only one person can enter data, but others can read it. iCloud is out as it only works for a single user account.

Is there a lightweight way to sync this datastore out from the single write user to the other read users? Setting up a full sync system seems overkill for this case.

Comment: You can set a flag or credential something for the person you want to provide the ability to write data and whenever there is a writing command check that flag or credential and then do things likewise...its just a way to implement what you trying to do there are other logics too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iCloud, you could use one of the online backends such as [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) or [Simperium](http://www.simperium.com). They would allow you to share data using a db and also provide for user accounts, authentication etc. If you want to run the server locally you can investigate [DataKit](https://github.com/eaigner/DataKit/).

Comment: Simperium looks like what I want.